# Storing metadata to a remote server and local DB simultaneously, which one should be first?

Tags: c#, rest, transactions

I recently got in charge of a C# client program, and found out that the client saves metadata simultaneously both to a remote REST server and local DB.

The client stores them into the local DB after receiving 200 response from the REST server.

However, I think I should reverse the order. What if saving them in local DB fails after the client receives 200(success)? The orphaned metadata are left on a remote server, aren't they?

Comment: That is difficult to judge without knowing the reasons why data is stored in multiple locations, what are the use cases and requirements.  If the purpose of local storage is only in case of remote failure so that it can retried later, then the current method seems acceptable.

Comment: The program seems to be seeking for 'synchronization'...whenever the client does CRUD on local DB, it does the same on a remote server. Remote data can be changed by another client in real time but not many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is a question on what the local DB should represent.
Should it reflect what the service has, or should it reflect the latest updates?

If it's the first, then the order is correct - you don't want to change the local DB unless you know for sure that the remote server is up to date.

However, if it's the last, then the order is wrong - since storing to local DB usually have less reasons to fail (i.e. a net failure, for one thing) - then in this case storing to local DB first makes more sense, provided, of course, you have some way to retry to update the remote service until success is returned (without causing too big performance impact on the rest of the program)

Comment: There are two DBs on both sides and they should be synchronized. The remote REST server receives metadata and stores them into its DB.

Comment: I guess the last one you are referring to is appropriate for this case, right?

Comment: Yes, I get that the databases should be in sync, however there's always a master and a slave - so the real question is which one is the master. You always update the master first and the slave later.

Comment: The master database should be the remote server, then the first one you've referred to is correct I guess.

Comment: Yep. No point of updating the slave database if the master is not updated.